# How do I find all records of a model based on it's association with another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I would like to find is all Events, where event.event_date is in the future, and only get the top 3 events sorted by how many Users the event has associated with it. Events and Users are joined by a HABTM relationship. Here's what I tried:

```
@popular_events = Event.where("event_date >= ?", Time.now)
                           .find(:all, 
                                 :joins => :users,
                                 :group => 'event_id',
                                 :order => "users.count DESC",
                                 :limit => 10 )
```

I've tried a few other things with no luck. It is saying users.count is not a valid column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

believe it or not, this is a pain in the b*tt to do this with ActiveRecord. You will more or less have to rely on raw SQL to do it. Some answers here : http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/03/activerecord-group-by-count-and-joins/